# How do I append a value to each array item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code, it works but it just doesn't look right. I'm creating a string that I'm passing to the server through SSH:

```
... chmod -R 777 #{remote_path}/#{project}/#{items_to_chmod.join(' ' + remote_path + '/' + project + '/')} ...
```

The ugly thing is the first `"#{remote_path}/#{project}/"`, it's not being added to the first item value in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
"... chmod -R 777 #{ items_to_chmod.map{ |item| File.join(remote_path, project, item) }.join(" ") } ..."
```